# does `ndarray.flat.copy()` and `ndarray.flatten()` do the same thing

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Currently i have an array `arr`
of which i can get a flat copy of the array with:

```py
flat_arr = arr.flat.copy()
```

but this also gives a flat copy of the array:

```py
flat_arr = arr.flatten()
```

is there a diffrent between this 2 "methods".

relevant documention pages
[numpy.ndarray.flat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html#numpy.ndarray.flat)
[numpy.ndarray.flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)
[numpy.flatiter.copy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatiter.copy.html#numpy.flatiter.copy)

After some basic testing i could not find a case where they are not equal:

```py
import numpy as np

for _ in range(int(1e6)):
    arr = np.random.rand(7,8,12,3)
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(arr.flat.copy(), arr.flatten())
    assert type(arr.flat.copy()) == type(arr.flatten())  # edit: i added this after @mozway's comment
```

But I would still like a conformation by someone else.

Comment: Yes, it will do the same, but why use `arr.flat.copy()`?

Comment: Also note that your method to test if the methods are "the same" is flawed. For instance comparing `arr.ravel()` and `arr.flatten()` (`np.testing.assert_array_equal(arr.ravel(), arr.flatten())`) would pass the assertion but those two methods do not do the same thing. One creates a view, the other a copy.

Comment: @mozway because someone wrote it so 5 years ago :-)

Comment: `ndarray.flatten()` will call directly a C core function, which will iterate over the source array and populate a new array. Calling `ndarray.flat` will create an intermediate iterator object. The `copy()`  method of this iterator will call the same core function `PyArray_Flatten`. So, yes, they are internally the same.